# application domains and threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, applicationdomain

A quote from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kac2kdh.aspx

> One or more managed threads
>   (represented by
>   System.Threading.Thread) can run in
>   one or any number of application
>   domains within the same managed
>   process. Although each application
>   domain is started with a single
>   thread, code in that application
>   domain can create additional
>   application domains and additional
>   threads. **The result is that a managed
>   thread can move freely between
>   application domains inside the same
>   managed process**; you might have only
>   one thread moving among several
>   application domains.

I tried to write code with 2 application domains that share one thread. But i gave up. I have really no idea how this is possible. Could you give me a code sample for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by simply creating an object which is MarshalByRef in a separate AppDomain and then calling a method on that object.

Take for example the following class definition.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class Foo : MarshalByRefObject, IFoo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Other AppDomain");
    }
}
```

You can then use this definition to call into a separate AppDomain from the current one.  At the point the call writes to the Console you will have 1 thread in 2 AppDomains (at 2 different points in the call stack).  Here is the sample code for that.

```
public static void CallIntoOtherAppDomain()
{
    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Other Domain");
    var obj = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Foo).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Foo).FullName);
    var foo = (IFoo)obj;
    foo.SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: so Thread.GetDomain() is not fixed to the appdomain who created the thread. it is dynamic based on the current callstack... no i understand! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Call a method on an object of the other app domain.